# "The imported project microsoft.dotnet.props was not found" when using AWS Lambda function

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda

I have installed the .NET Core SDK as well as .NET Core Visual Studio 2015 Tooling Preview 2 along with AWS Visual Studio Toolkit as shown in the image below:

[image: Installation]

But even after installation, I am getting an error when trying to use the sample AWS Lambda function as shown in the image below:

[image: Error]

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Used Offline Installation of .NET Core SDK as well as .NET Core Visual Studio 2015 Tooling Preview 2.